# Blog, deleting user post

Tags: php, post, blogs

I made a blog where a user can post things, well what else does one do on a blog?
Anyways, I want the user to be able to delete his or her post.  I have no idea where to even start with this. 
The data is posted to the page with this while loop:

```
 while($posts=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
     $tasks=$posts['task'];
     $time=$posts['time'];
     $date=$posts['date'];    
echo '<p id="tasks">'.$tasks. '</p><p id="date">'.$date.'</p><p id="time">'.$time.'</p><hr />';
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a form with checkboxes against the various posts of the user. the user would check the box against the post he wants to delete. on submitting the form, do a sql query to delete the posts (use the primary key of the posts table to identif which post the user wants to delete.

Answer (score 0):

in your database create a user_deleted or similar with default of no.

In the users profile list all the post's with checkbox to delete, with the delete button at the bottom, on delete update the table to change user_delete from no to yes.

When displaying posts in your mysqli_query add WHERE user_deleted = 'no'

Then the only posts that will display will be the ones that are set to no.